# Poetry not installing the packages in the venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, python-poetry

I'am new to Poetry and I have an issue that I couldn't find much info about online. My poetry is supposed to create a virtual env of python 3.9, and it did. Here's what I got with the commande `poetry env info`:

```
Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.10
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /home/..../.venv
Valid:          True

System
Platform: linux
OS:       posix
Python:   /usr
```

And when I type `poetry shell` then `python` , I did get into a python 3.9 and I was able to import the packages that installed. But here's the weird part. When I tried to checked one of the packages that installed, here's what I got:

```
>>> import XXX.python_utils as utils
>>> utils
<module 'XXX.python_utils' from '/home/X/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/XXX/python_utils/__init__.py'>
```

I do have a actual python 3.9 installed in my machine, but Poetry is supposed to install the package in the virtualenv instead of the actual python3.9 site_packages right? I then tried my python 3.9 installed in my machine instead of virtual env, the packages can still be imported. The outcome is the same as above.

Then I double checked what's in the `.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, there's basically nothing inside. What I did found is some repositories with the name of the package and ends with `.dist-info`. I'm not sure what's that about.

I also tried `which python` in the `poetry shell`, and here's what I got:

```
(.venv) XXX@XXX:~/XXX$ which python
/home/.../.venv/bin/python
```

It seems like poetry does use the python 3.9 in the venv

And finally, everytime I ran a `poetry install`, it install all the packages even I didn't change anything in my `pyproject.yaml` It seems like the `poetry.lock` means nothing.

Answer (score 7):

you could try:

```
poetry env remove python
poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
```

and then execute following commands in your project folder:

```
poetry shell
poetry add your_lib
poetry install
```

the ***poetry env remove python*** will clean your global python env, and the ***poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true*** will tell poetry only create .venv in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

> `/home/X/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

That's not "actual python3.9 site-packages" (i.e. system python3.9 site-packages), that's [your PEP 370 per-user site-packages directory](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/). Is it possible you've installed the packages (or some of them) without Poetry or a vanilla virtual environment enabled? It could well be possible that Poetry decides not to install dependencies in the project venv that are ambiently available in your local site-packages already.

You can use `pip list --user` without a virtualenv activated to see what packages have been installed in that local directory, and use e.g. `pip uninstall` to uninstall them.

You could also see what happens if you move that directory out of the way (e.g. rename `python3.9` to `python3.9-temporarily-out-of-the-way`) and ask Poetry to install packages.

Comment: I rename the ```lib/python3.9``` to another name and I ran ```poetry install``` again. The result is the same I got exactly the same outcome. But when I checked ```/.local/lib/```, I found that a new repository ```python3.9``` has been created

Comment: So the dependencies were (re)installed in `~/.local/lib/python3.9` and not the venv?

Comment: Yes. There's still nothing in the venv/lib

Comment: Hmm – maybe get rid of the `.local` site-packages once more and try with `poetry -vvv install` for debug-level verbosity? The output should have some clues...